# Session save delayed in php

Tags: php, ajax, session

I have the following problem: I have two pages. In the first page is a button. When the button is clicked, an ajax request is made to a page that saves data to the session. Then, it redirects me to the second page in which I display this saved data. The problem is that when I go to the second page the data is not displayed, but when I refresh the page the data is displayed. How can I redirect to the second page with the session data stored?

Example:

Before Refresh:

[image: Before Refresh]

After:

[image: After]

Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: If giving example images, post them to the question. Do not link to external objects since they may not be there in the future.

Comment: You could probably just add a small delay after your Ajax request returns successfully and before you redirect the user. Actual code would help.

Comment: a setTimeOut for example?

Comment: you should edit your question to A. post the external objects and B. post your current Ajax code.

Comment: i fixed it on complete callback i redirected to the other page

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should wait for the response of the AJAX request before you forward to the next page.

Preferable use the callback method to redirect to the next page.

If you post some code may be it will be easier to point out.

Comment: How much time must I wait?

Comment: Thats the point with callback. You dont have to wait. Once server sends a response it means(I am assuming) the data was set to session.

Comment: now i understand i will make oncomplete callback to redirect me to the page thank you

Answer (score 0):

Try this, hope it'll work
if you are using jQuery then fine, use e.preventDefault(); and redirect your next page after getting the ajax response.